# Properly updating RealmModel after onClick without blocking the UI in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm, realm-list

I have a `RecyclerView` which displays items from a `Realm` database. 
To do so I have implemented a `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` based on the [realm-android-adapters](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters) which gets an `OrderedRealmCollection` passed in. 
For this I load the data with `findAllAsync()`

```
realm.where(Entry.class).findAllAsync()
```

When the user scrolls through the list he has the option to "favorite" some of the entries, which I have implemented with a normal `OnClickListener` on the "favorite" button.

Now I would love to update the "favorite" boolean of the entry whenever the user clicks the button. After the user clicked, a small animation is shown on the button.

For this I tried the following which sadly gives a wrong thread exception:

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        entry.setLiked(!entry.isLiked());
    }
});
```

As an alternative I tried it with the normal `executeTransaction` which will work, but prevent the animation from being shown.

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        entry.setLiked(!entry.isLiked());
    }
});
```

As an interesting addition this gives the following log:

> Mixing asynchronous queries with local writes should be avoided. Realm will convert any async queries to synchronous in order to remain consistent. Use asynchronous writes instead.

Is there any possibility to update the item completely async without introducing lag or preventing the animation from being shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` calls `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when your Realm gets auto-updated, so the layout animation won't be called.

As for actually doing the change,

```
public class EntryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.entry_favorite)
    Button favButton;

    public EntryViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }

    public void bind(Entry entry) {
        final long entryId = entry.getId();
        favButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                     @Override
                     public void execute(Realm realm) {
                         Entry entry = realm.where(Entry.class)
                                            .equalTo("id", id)
                                            .findFirst();
                         if(entry != null) {
                             entry.deleteFromRealm();
                         }
                     }
                 });
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right it was simply related to the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` preventing the application. completely overlooked that this will also be triggered each time I update. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Execute this on a background Thread. I recommend using classic Thread.class .Start animation outisde new Thread, and dismiss it through a callback on the UI Thread.

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(..);
realm.beginTransaction();
YourClass yourClassInstance = realm.where(YourClass.class)
        .equalTo(..)
        .findFirst();
if(yourClassInstance != null){
   yourClassInstance.setLiked(!yourClassInstance.getLiked());
}else{
   yourClassInstance = realm.createObject(YourClass.class);
   yourClassInstance.setLiked(whateverYouWant);
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```